# popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't clear the back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

When my app is 2 levels into the navigation stack, I call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`. The `rootViewController` then becomes visible, but there is still a back button that you have to click on to actually get back to the root without a back button.

Is there something else I need to do to pop to the root without that back button?

Comment: just guessing (cannot test it right now): maybe you have pushed the same instance of your rootVC to the navigationContr. ? if this is the problem: avoid pushing the same instance again to the navContr ;)

Comment: The actual sequence is root->A->B then popViewControllerAnimated to A, push to B, and then popToRootViewControllerAnimated to root. Would that sequence cause this problem?

Comment: no, should not. but the fact that you are getting the rootVC with a back button seems to be a duplicated rootVC. Can you please set a breakpoint before `popToRoot` and print out the `[navigationController viewControllers]` which results in the list of all added viewControllers

Comment: just before popToRoot, there are 3 viewControllers where index 0 is the rootViewController. At viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, there is only one viewController at index 0, and that is the rootViewController. But when I continue execution and I see the view, there is a back button. Any other thoughts?

Comment: what I meant to say is that after popToRoot, at viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, there is only one viewController at index 0, and that is the rootViewController. But when I continue execution and I see the view, there is a back button. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @thomas, I had a typo in my second comment. The actual sequence is root->A->B, then popViewControllerAnimated to A with an immediate push to C, and then popToRootViewControllerAnimated from C.

Comment: @thomas, If I only do pushes to get from root->A->B and then popViewControllerAnimated to get back to A and a subsequent popViewControllerAnimated to get back to the root, then there is no problem (i.e. no back button on the root view). NOTE that the push to both B and to C was done from viewWillAppear. So it appears that either there is a problem with popToRootViewControllerAnimated, or there is some race condition with the approach I took that confuses popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are pushing views in `viewWillAppear`. Try to set a breakpoint to that method and to all lines of code where sth. gets pushed and take look at the sequence of execution. I guess that `viewWillAppear` will be called when you are popping back to rootVC: So a `popToRoot` with current stack of root->A->b will return to root which then calls `viewWillAppear` which pushes again a VC.

Comment: I think you are right. That makes sense. I kind of needed to start my push sequence from viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad. So, I think I will just change my design to do something slightly different. Thanks for your input.