# Can't hide back button after popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a NavigationController whose first view controller is a "decision maker" class that doesn't have any UI. So with that as the root, the local database is checked and if we have certain items, the decision maker VC will push a certain VC, or if there are no items, it will push a different VC.  So it's really like a tree with 2 branches.

At a certain point in branch 1, we have a few VCs pushed to the stack and the user might delete the last of their "items", so I want to call popToRootViewControllerAnimated and have my decision maker route correctly to branch 2.  Everything works fine, except in the navigation bar, I can't get rid of the back button in the first VC on branch 2 which contains the title of the last VC it was at in branch 1.

Here's the navigation diagrammatically (sort of):

```
NavController
DecisionMaker
   branch1VC1
      branch1VC2
         branch1VC3
   branch2VC1
      branch2VC2
```

If we are at branch1VC3 and I delete the last item then call popToRootViewControllerAnimated, it goes thru the DecisionMaker and correctly lands at branch2VC1, but it has a back button with the label "branch1VC3".  The button doesn't do anything when you press it. I also notice that when I click a different button - which takes you to an "About page" - in the bottom nav bar, the normal back button I would see at the top of the About page is not there so I have no way of returning.  Basically the nav is screwed by this point.

I have tried:

- calling self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES in the destination VC (branch2VC1) but it doesn't work.
- calling self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = NULL in same.
- calling self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = NULL in same (all of these tried in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear)
- setting self.title to null in the DecisionMaker VC.  This just has the effect of turning the text inside the back button to "Back", but it's still there once it finishes navigating to the VC.
- debugging to see that the VCs I thought were on the stack definitely were, i.e. inside the DecisionMaker VC there's only 1 (itself) and inside the branch2VC1 there are 2.

Basically, to me it seems like the thing at fault is probably the pop to root action being in the same UI cycle as the new push to the other branch.  But I can't see why that should be not do-able.  I found [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998348/poptorootviewcontrolleranimated-doesnt-clear-the-back-button) which I think is probably the same but didn't really have any answers.

**EDIT:**
The resolution was to call super.viewWillAppear on the DecisionMaker VC before doing any of my custom logic & navigation.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self decideViewController];
}
```

Comment: Are DecisionMaker a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: @Dhara I've asked 5 questions including this one, and the only one of those which was answered (correctly, i.e. it solved my problem) by someone other than myself, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will almomst always be problems with the view hierarchy if they are pushed in `viewWillAppear`, or somewhere before the new UI has loaded correctly. Make sure that the new views are pushed at the correct time.

Comment: That's sounding like it might be a lot to do with the issue.  I don't have my code in front of me so can't test it out until I get back to work tomorrow, but I know that the pushes happen in viewWillAppear...which as you point out doesn't make sense as the right place to do it.  Thanks.  If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @bobsmells I'm having the same issue, can you elaborate on how you solved it with a code example?

Comment: @dbau I don't have that code in front of me, and won't be back at work until Monday.  (I have a very old copy of the code here but I just checked it out and it still has that issue).  I'll set a reminder to myself to get back to you then ok?

Comment: Sorry for the wait @dbau, I had to arrange to get hold of the single Mac that this place owns so that I could get a copy of the working final build...took a while so my apologies.

Comment: Sorry for the wait @dbau, I had to arrange to get hold of the single Mac that this place owns so that I could get a copy of the working final build...took a while so my apologies.  Ok the important bit in the working version is that in the viewWillAppear on the DecisionMaker VC, I now call super.viewWillAppear FIRST, before my logic that does the check and segue. So by that point, all the important stuff alluded to by Martol1ni has been done.  Will edit original post above.